# If else if shortening

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I can see there are so many related questions to this. Could not find anything specific addressing my query. Here is my question:

How can i shorten the below if else condition:

```
If (condition1)
{
    If(condition2)
    {
        Logic A
    }
}
Else if (condition3)
{
    Logic A
}
```

One way i could come up was as below:

```
If (condition1 && condition2  ||  !condition1 && condition3)
{
    Logic A
}
```

Just wondering if there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: If you're looking for shorter, your solution is definitely shorter. But keep in mind shorter does not always mean better!

Comment: @djfdev, your suggestion will not work because it will execute logic when condition2 is false

Comment: I dont wanna execute Logic A at all, if condition1 is true and condition2 is false.

Comment: In your case optimization should be made from readability point of view, because it will not have affect on the performance. From readability point of view your original approach is easier to follow than shortened version.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for the answer. I agree with your point.

Comment: @Fabio But my other doubt when i go with first approach is that - amn't I replicating the same code (Logic A) in multiple places - not sure if it is a good thing or not?

Comment: @user2881636, if logic A wrapped with the method, then you not replicated but delegating to the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case optimization is important only from readability point of view. From OP examples I would prefer original one, because it easier to follow for developer/reader who didn't write this code.

We execute one action or do nothing based on conditions, so I would wrap every condition chain which leads to the execution into the method with descriptive name and used them with `or` operator.

```
// condition 1 = customer.persisted
// condition 2 = bonuses.has(customer.id)
// condition 3 = promotionCodes.has(customer.promotionCode)
function whenExistingCustomerWithBonus() {
  return customer.persisted && bonuses.has(customer.id);
}

function whenGuestCustomerWithPromotionCode() {
  return customer.persisted === false && promotionCodes.has(customer.promotionCode);
}

// Usage

if (whenExistingCustomerWithBonus() || whenGuestCustomerWithPromotionCode()) {
  // execute logic A
}
```

Comment: I like this. Instead if separate functions , i think just variables would do right?  var whenExistingCustomerWithBonus = customer.persisted && bonuses.has(customer.id);

Comment: Functions wraps condition with descriptive name, variables will do same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```js
(condition1 && condition2  ||  !condition1 && condition3) ?  logic(a) : logic(b)
```

Its called Ternary operator, It would make your code shorter and you can also use it to set a variable, for example

```
const isTrue = 4 > 3 ? true : false
```

Comment: I dont have multiple logic to execute. It is logic A needs to be executed in both cases. And I dont wanna execute Logic A at all, if condition1 is true and condition2 is false.

Comment: in that case you can do `condition ? logic(a) : null`

Comment: @BahaaaldinMohammad, in that case you don't need ternary operator ;)

Comment: Ternary operator works only when you assign the result to a variable. `(condition1 && condition2  ||  !condition1 && condition3) ?  logic(a) : logic(b)` so this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are some aspects that you must keep in mind.

- It's possible that a shorter code be faster in some script languages (like JavaScript, PHP...).
- But it worth? Is your if inside a loop long enough to make any difference in your code execution time?
- Do your shortened code makes easier or harder to understand your code? Sometimes joining some if conditions inside a boolean logic makes it easier to understand, but sometimes it's so complicated that is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes its possible to simplify (note the use of the word 'simplify' instead of 'shorten') conditional logic by reversing it, or by delegating logic to other functions, or a combination of both:

given this:

```
function performLogic() {
  if (condition a) {
    if (condition b) {
      logic 1
    }
  } else {
    logic 1
  }
}
```

let's try to think about this in reverse:

```
function performLogic() {
  if (!condition a) logic 1
  else if (conditoin b) logic 1
}
```

keep in mind this kind of refactor will not always be possible, and i also advise you to write unit tests for the logic to ensure that the end result remains the same.

It can also sometimes be simplified further depending on the logic in the function. many times we can replace conditional logic with guard clauses like this:

```
function getSomeValue() {
  if (condition a) {
    if (condition b) {
      ... do some logic
      return someValue;
    }
  }
}
```

this can be changed to

```
function getSomeValue() {
  if (!condition a) return;
  if (!condition b) return;

  ... do some logic
  return someValue;
}
```

Comment: Do we need to add `return` statement after executing logic in first condition, because otherwise it will execute it twice when `condition1 = false` and `condition2 = true`. And you forgot about condition 3, which proves that _this will not always work_ :)

Comment: well this is pseudo-code so feel free to fix, i'm just trying to get the idea across

Comment: That was my point, that when you actually write the code for another approach it will looks the same with no benefit

Comment: @duxfox-- I like that you used the word simplify and thanks for all the directions. But these doesnt answer my specific scenario.